# How comparing object item elements in an array with reduce?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object, reduce

I have array

```
 const example = [{ day: 5, month: 1, key: 1 },{ day: 5, month: 1, key: 2 },{ day: 3, month: 3, key: 3 },{ day: 5, month: 1, key: 4 },{ day: 3, month: 3, key: 5 },{ day: 11, month: 4, key: 6 }];
```

how to check the elements of the day and month when the same ? if the year and month are repeated I would like the result return

`{err:'the same',index:[0,1,2,3]}`

My code not working.

```
const duplicates = Object.entries(array).reduce((acc, item, index) => {
  if (acc[1].year === item[1].year && acc[1].month === item[1].month) {
    return [
      {
        index:[acc[0],acc[1]],
        err: "the same"
      }
    ];
  }
return acc;});
```

Answer (score 1):

- Iterate over the array using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of the day-month as the `key` and its occurrence indices as the `value`.
- Using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), get the entries that have more than one index.
- After that, return the list using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
const array = [ { day: 5, month: 1, key: 1 }, { day: 5, month: 1, key: 2 }, { day: 3, month: 3, key: 3 }, { day: 5, month: 1, key: 4 }, { day: 3, month: 3, key: 5 }, { day: 11, month: 4, key: 6 } ];

const duplicates = [...array
.reduce((map, { day, month }, index) => {
  const key = `${day}-${month}`;
  map.set(key, [...(map.get(key) || []), index]);
  return map;
}, new Map)
.values()]
.filter(indices => indices.length > 1)
.map(indices => ({ err: "the same", index: indices }));

console.log(duplicates);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `Map` constructor to build a map keyed by (unique) year-month values, and where the associated values are arrays of error objects, initialised with an empty `index` array. Then populate those `index` arrays, and get those that have more than one entry. This involves no `reduce`:

```js
const example = [{ day: 5, month: 1, key: 1 },{ day: 5, month: 1, key: 2 },{ day: 3, month: 3, key: 3 },{ day: 5, month: 1, key: 4 },{ day: 3, month: 3, key: 5 },{ day: 11, month: 4, key: 6 }];

const map = new Map(example.map(o => 
    [o.month * 100 + o.day, {err: "the same", index: []}]
));
example.forEach((o, i) => map.get(o.month * 100 + o.day).index.push(i));
const dupes = Array.from(map.values()).filter(o => o.index.length > 1);
console.log(dupes);
```